# No puedo consumir método webservice en java

Tags: java, webservice, soap, wsdl

Necesito ayuda para consumir un método de un webservice pero no he tenido éxito hasta el momento.

El método:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Header>
    <LoginInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <Username>[string?]</Username>
        <Password>[string?]</Password>
        <Company>[string?]</Company>
    </LoginInfo>
</Header>
<Body>
    <GetCarsInfoNew xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <DeviceID>[string?]</DeviceID>
    </GetCarsInfoNew>
</Body>
```

Esta es la forma en que trato:

```
if(wbs.Autenticacion()){
       System.out.println("Conectado como "+wbs.login.getUsername());
       System.out.println( wbs.port.getCarsInfoNew("xxxxxxx"));
   }
```

[image: imagen netbeans]

Y este el error que muestra:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
```